# View optimization in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, view, correlated-subquery

I have to aggregate the very last 'reading' from each table in a single view in order to optimize database access but I've noticed that executing many single queries cost much less than using a view so I'm wondering if there is something wrong in my view or it can be optimized.

Here some tables:

```
CREATE TABLE hives(
  id character(20) NOT NULL,
  master character(20) DEFAULT NULL::bpchar,
  owner integer,
  [...]
  CONSTRAINT hives_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT hives_master_extk FOREIGN KEY (master)
      REFERENCES hives (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT hives_owner_extk FOREIGN KEY (owner)
      REFERENCES users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE dt_rain(
  hive character(20) NOT NULL,
  hiveconnection integer,
  instant timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  rain integer,
  CONSTRAINT dt_rain_pkey PRIMARY KEY (hive, instant),
  CONSTRAINT dt_rain_hive_connections_extk FOREIGN KEY (hiveconnection)
      REFERENCES hives_connections (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT dt_rain_hive_extk FOREIGN KEY (hive)
      REFERENCES hives (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE dt_temperature
(
  hive character(20) NOT NULL,
  hiveconnection integer,
  instant timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  internal integer,
  external integer,
  CONSTRAINT dt_temperature_pkey PRIMARY KEY (hive, instant),
  CONSTRAINT dt_temperature_hive_connections_extk FOREIGN KEY (hiveconnection)
      REFERENCES hives_connections (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT dt_temperature_hive_extk FOREIGN KEY (hive)
      REFERENCES hives (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Every **data table** holds an history of all readings and are very large and share the same format: **hive** (key to hives table), **instant**, ***data***.

I'm interested in obtaining only the last value so here is the view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dt_last AS
SELECT id AS 
    hive, 
    b.instant AS inout_instant, "input", "output", timeout, 
    c.instant AS temperature_instant, "internal", "external", 
    d.instant AS weight_instant, weight, 
    e.instant AS rain_instant, rain, 
    f.instant AS voltage_instant, operational, panel, cell, 
    g.instant AS gps_instant, latitude, longitude, altitude
FROM hives 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT hive, instant, "input", "output", timeout FROM dt_inout_summary x
        WHERE x.instant = (
            SELECT MAX(x1.instant) FROM dt_inout_summary x1 WHERE x1.hive = x.hive
        )
    ) b ON (id = b.hive) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT hive, instant, "internal", "external" FROM dt_temperature x
        WHERE x.instant = (
            SELECT MAX(x1.instant) FROM dt_temperature x1 WHERE x1.hive = x.hive
        )
    ) c ON (id = c.hive) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT hive, instant, weight FROM dt_weight x
        WHERE x.instant = (
            SELECT MAX(x1.instant) FROM dt_weight x1 WHERE x1.hive = x.hive
        )
    ) d ON (id = d.hive) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT hive, instant, rain FROM dt_rain x
        WHERE x.instant = (
            SELECT MAX(x1.instant) FROM dt_inout_summary x1 WHERE x1.hive = x.hive
        )
    ) e ON (id = e.hive) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT hive, instant, operational, panel, cell FROM dt_voltage x
        WHERE x.instant = (
            SELECT MAX(x1.instant) FROM dt_inout_summary x1 WHERE x1.hive = x.hive
        )
    ) f ON (id = f.hive) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT hive, instant, latitude, longitude, altitude FROM dt_gps x
        WHERE x.instant = (
            SELECT MAX(x1.instant) FROM dt_gps x1 WHERE x1.hive = x.hive
        )
    ) g ON (id = g.hive)
```

Selecting from this view costs about 1 second per record wich is much more expensive than executing **SELECT * FROM  WHERE hive='' ORDER BY instant DESC Limit 1;** six times per hive.
I'm puzzled

Here is a graphical view of the query analyzer followed by EXPLAIN ANALYZE output
[image: planner]

```
    Merge Left Join  (cost=127051.81..264142.76 rows=37741 width=153) (actual time=8862.466..8862.564 rows=13 loops=1)
  Merge Cond: (hives.id = x_1.hive)
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.29..136523.11 rows=801 width=137) (actual time=4198.324..4198.395 rows=13 loops=1)
        Join Filter: (hives.id = x_5.hive)
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 36
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.29..136505.79 rows=801 width=85) (actual time=4198.300..4198.363 rows=13 loops=1)
              Join Filter: (hives.id = x_4.hive)
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.29..135968.88 rows=801 width=65) (actual time=4198.254..4198.315 rows=13 loops=1)
                    Join Filter: (hives.id = x_3.hive)
                    Rows Removed by Join Filter: 12
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.29..135407.01 rows=801 width=53) (actual time=4198.171..4198.227 rows=13 loops=1)
                          Join Filter: (hives.id = x.hive)
                          Rows Removed by Join Filter: 108
                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.29..345.31 rows=17 width=33) (actual time=0.011..0.049 rows=13 loops=1)
                                ->  Index Only Scan using hives_pkey on hives  (cost=0.14..12.39 rows=17 width=21) (actual time=0.005..0.011 rows=13 loops=1)
                                      Heap Fetches: 13
                                ->  Index Scan using dt_weight_pkey on dt_weight x_2  (cost=0.15..19.57 rows=1 width=96) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=13)
                                      Index Cond: (hives.id = hive)
                                      Filter: (instant = (SubPlan 6))
                                      SubPlan 6
                                        ->  Result  (cost=5.50..5.51 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=1)
                                              InitPlan 5 (returns $5)
                                                ->  Limit  (cost=0.15..5.50 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                      ->  Index Only Scan Backward using dt_weight_pkey on dt_weight x1_2  (cost=0.15..16.21 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                            Index Cond: ((hive = x_2.hive) AND (instant IS NOT NULL))
                                                            Heap Fetches: 1
                          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..134859.45 rows=801 width=41) (actual time=198.865..322.935 rows=9 loops=13)
                                ->  Seq Scan on dt_inout_summary x  (cost=0.00..134855.44 rows=801 width=41) (actual time=2585.238..4198.146 rows=9 loops=1)
                                      Filter: (instant = (SubPlan 2))
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 160099
                                      SubPlan 2
                                        ->  Result  (cost=0.81..0.82 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.026..0.026 rows=1 loops=160108)
                                              InitPlan 1 (returns $1)
                                                ->  Limit  (cost=0.42..0.81 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.025..0.025 rows=1 loops=160108)
                                                      ->  Index Only Scan Backward using test on dt_inout_summary x1  (cost=0.42..6929.02 rows=17790 width=8) (actual time=0.025..0.025 rows=1 loops=160108)
                                                            Index Cond: ((hive = x.hive) AND (instant IS NOT NULL))
                                                            Heap Fetches: 160108
                    ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..525.83 rows=3 width=96) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=13)
                          ->  Seq Scan on dt_rain x_3  (cost=0.00..525.82 rows=3 width=96) (actual time=0.076..0.076 rows=1 loops=1)
                                Filter: (instant = (SubPlan 8))
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 2
                                SubPlan 8
                                  ->  Result  (cost=0.81..0.82 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.023..0.023 rows=1 loops=3)
                                        InitPlan 7 (returns $7)
                                          ->  Limit  (cost=0.42..0.81 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.023..0.023 rows=1 loops=3)
                                                ->  Index Only Scan Backward using test on dt_inout_summary x1_3  (cost=0.42..6929.02 rows=17790 width=8) (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=1 loops=3)
                                                      Index Cond: ((hive = x_3.hive) AND (instant IS NOT NULL))
                                                      Heap Fetches: 3
              ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..500.88 rows=3 width=104) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=13)
                    ->  Seq Scan on dt_voltage x_4  (cost=0.00..500.86 rows=3 width=104) (actual time=0.045..0.045 rows=0 loops=1)
                          Filter: (instant = (SubPlan 10))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 2
                          SubPlan 10
                            ->  Result  (cost=0.81..0.82 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.021..0.021 rows=1 loops=2)
                                  InitPlan 9 (returns $9)
                                    ->  Limit  (cost=0.42..0.81 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.020..0.020 rows=1 loops=2)
                                          ->  Index Only Scan Backward using test on dt_inout_summary x1_4  (cost=0.42..6929.02 rows=17790 width=8) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=1 loops=2)
                                                Index Cond: ((hive = x_4.hive) AND (instant IS NOT NULL))
                                                Heap Fetches: 2
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..5.30 rows=1 width=136) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=3 loops=13)
              ->  Seq Scan on dt_gps x_5  (cost=0.00..5.30 rows=1 width=136) (actual time=0.009..0.018 rows=3 loops=1)
                    Filter: (instant = (SubPlan 11))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 3
                    SubPlan 11
                      ->  Aggregate  (cost=1.05..1.06 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=6)
                            ->  Seq Scan on dt_gps x1_5  (cost=0.00..1.05 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=3 loops=6)
                                  Filter: (hive = x_5.hive)
                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 3
  ->  Sort  (cost=127051.53..127053.53 rows=801 width=37) (actual time=4664.139..4664.139 rows=9 loops=1)
        Sort Key: x_1.hive
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Seq Scan on dt_temperature x_1  (cost=0.00..127012.90 rows=801 width=37) (actual time=2859.376..4664.118 rows=9 loops=1)
              Filter: (instant = (SubPlan 4))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 160098
              SubPlan 4
                ->  Result  (cost=0.76..0.77 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.029..0.029 rows=1 loops=160107)
                      InitPlan 3 (returns $3)
                        ->  Limit  (cost=0.42..0.76 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.028..0.028 rows=1 loops=160107)
                              ->  Index Only Scan Backward using dt_temperature_pkey on dt_temperature x1_1  (cost=0.42..6834.25 rows=20013 width=8) (actual time=0.028..0.028 rows=1 loops=160107)
                                    Index Cond: ((hive = x_1.hive) AND (instant IS NOT NULL))
                                    Heap Fetches: 160107
Total runtime: 8862.684 ms
```

Is there a way to optimize this view in any way?

=== EDIT as suggested by joop with MAX replaced with NOT EXISTS and indexes (hive, instant desc)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dt_last4 AS 
 SELECT hives.id AS hive,
    b.instant AS inout_instant,
    b.input,
    b.output,
    b.timeout,
    c.instant AS temperature_instant,
    c.internal,
    c.external,
    d.instant AS weight_instant,
    d.weight,
    e.instant AS rain_instant,
    e.rain,
    f.instant AS voltage_instant,
    f.operational,
    f.panel,
    f.cell,
    g.instant AS gps_instant,
    g.latitude,
    g.longitude,
    g.altitude
   FROM hives
     LEFT JOIN dt_inout_summary b ON b.hive = hives.id AND NOT (EXISTS ( SELECT 1
           FROM dt_inout_summary nx
          WHERE nx.hive = b.hive AND nx.instant > b.instant))
     LEFT JOIN dt_temperature c ON c.hive = hives.id AND NOT (EXISTS ( SELECT 1
           FROM dt_temperature nx
          WHERE nx.hive = c.hive AND nx.instant > c.instant))
     LEFT JOIN dt_weight d ON d.hive = hives.id AND NOT (EXISTS ( SELECT 1
           FROM dt_weight nx
          WHERE nx.hive = d.hive AND nx.instant > d.instant))
     LEFT JOIN dt_rain e ON e.hive = hives.id AND NOT (EXISTS ( SELECT 1
           FROM dt_rain nx
          WHERE nx.hive = e.hive AND nx.instant > e.instant))
     LEFT JOIN dt_voltage f ON f.hive = hives.id AND NOT (EXISTS ( SELECT 1
           FROM dt_voltage nx
          WHERE nx.hive = f.hive AND nx.instant > f.instant))
     LEFT JOIN dt_gps g ON g.hive = hives.id AND NOT (EXISTS ( SELECT 1
           FROM dt_gps nx
          WHERE nx.hive = g.hive AND nx.instant > g.instant));
```

EXPLAIN ANALYZE:
[image]

```
Hash Left Join  (cost=18746.60..17942207.21 rows=670182787 width=153) (actual time=771.791..3488.536 rows=13 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (hives.id = e.hive)
  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=18744.45..14640569.26 rows=670182787 width=141) (actual time=771.776..3488.513 rows=13 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (hives.id = f.hive)
        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=18742.35..11733156.54 rows=670182787 width=121) (actual time=771.759..3488.486 rows=13 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (hives.id = g.hive)
              ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=18740.04..7643068.10 rows=670182787 width=69) (actual time=771.730..3488.447 rows=13 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (b.hive = hives.id)
                    ->  Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=0.84..81545.46 rows=106739 width=41) (actual time=585.381..3301.662 rows=9 loops=1)
                          ->  Index Scan using dt_inout_summary_hive_idx on dt_inout_summary b  (cost=0.42..11549.35 rows=160108 width=41) (actual time=0.012..33.690 rows=160108 loops=1)
                          ->  Index Only Scan using dt_inout_summary_hive_instant_idx on dt_inout_summary nx  (cost=0.42..119.09 rows=5930 width=29) (actual time=0.020..0.020 rows=1 loops=160108)
                                Index Cond: ((hive = b.hive) AND (instant > b.instant))
                                Heap Fetches: 160099
                    ->  Hash  (cost=16361.97..16361.97 rows=106738 width=49) (actual time=186.324..186.324 rows=13 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 2048  Batches: 16  Memory Usage: 1kB
                          ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=6197.92..16361.97 rows=106738 width=49) (actual time=109.280..186.247 rows=13 loops=1)
                                Hash Cond: (c.hive = hives.id)
                                ->  Hash Anti Join  (cost=6194.41..14890.81 rows=106738 width=37) (actual time=109.245..186.196 rows=9 loops=1)
                                      Hash Cond: (c.hive = nx_1.hive)
                                      Join Filter: (nx_1.instant > c.instant)
                                      Rows Removed by Join Filter: 195309
                                      ->  Seq Scan on dt_temperature c  (cost=0.00..3098.07 rows=160107 width=37) (actual time=0.004..18.177 rows=160107 loops=1)
                                      ->  Hash  (cost=3098.07..3098.07 rows=160107 width=29) (actual time=48.792..48.792 rows=160107 loops=1)
                                            Buckets: 2048  Batches: 32 (originally 16)  Memory Usage: 4175kB
                                            ->  Seq Scan on dt_temperature nx_1  (cost=0.00..3098.07 rows=160107 width=29) (actual time=0.002..17.848 rows=160107 loops=1)
                                ->  Hash  (cost=3.30..3.30 rows=17 width=33) (actual time=0.029..0.029 rows=13 loops=1)
                                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                                      ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=2.06..3.30 rows=17 width=33) (actual time=0.023..0.028 rows=13 loops=1)
                                            Hash Cond: (hives.id = d.hive)
                                            ->  Seq Scan on hives  (cost=0.00..1.17 rows=17 width=21) (actual time=0.004..0.006 rows=13 loops=1)
                                            ->  Hash  (cost=2.04..2.04 rows=1 width=33) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                  Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                                                  ->  Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=0.00..2.04 rows=1 width=33) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                        Join Filter: ((nx_2.instant > d.instant) AND (nx_2.hive = d.hive))
                                                        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1
                                                        ->  Seq Scan on dt_weight d  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=33) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=29) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                              ->  Seq Scan on dt_weight nx_2  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=29) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)
              ->  Hash  (cost=2.26..2.26 rows=4 width=136) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=3 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                    ->  Hash Anti Join  (cost=1.14..2.26 rows=4 width=136) (actual time=0.015..0.018 rows=3 loops=1)
                          Hash Cond: (g.hive = nx_5.hive)
                          Join Filter: (nx_5.instant > g.instant)
                          Rows Removed by Join Filter: 9
                          ->  Seq Scan on dt_gps g  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=6 width=136) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=6 loops=1)
                          ->  Hash  (cost=1.06..1.06 rows=6 width=92) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=6 loops=1)
                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                                ->  Seq Scan on dt_gps nx_5  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=6 width=92) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=6 loops=1)
        ->  Hash  (cost=2.08..2.08 rows=1 width=104) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
              ->  Hash Anti Join  (cost=1.04..2.08 rows=1 width=104) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (f.hive = nx_4.hive)
                    Join Filter: (nx_4.instant > f.instant)
                    Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2
                    ->  Seq Scan on dt_voltage f  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=2 width=104) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=2 loops=1)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=1.02..1.02 rows=2 width=92) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=2 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on dt_voltage nx_4  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=2 width=92) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=2 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=2.13..2.13 rows=2 width=96) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=2 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
        ->  Hash Anti Join  (cost=1.07..2.13 rows=2 width=96) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=2 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (e.hive = nx_3.hive)
              Join Filter: (nx_3.instant > e.instant)
              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 3
              ->  Seq Scan on dt_rain e  (cost=0.00..1.03 rows=3 width=96) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=3 loops=1)
              ->  Hash  (cost=1.03..1.03 rows=3 width=92) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=3 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on dt_rain nx_3  (cost=0.00..1.03 rows=3 width=92) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=3 loops=1)
Total runtime: 3488.684 ms
```

This forth version is much much better. There still remains some sequential scans. Without them this view will be a state of pure art!

Comment: REPLACE THE `MAX(...)` by corresponding `NOT EXISTS(...)` constructs. And add an index `ON dt_inout_summary (hive, instant DESC)` Also for the other daughter tables. And please add the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to your question. The graphic may look sexy, but is relatively useless.

Comment: You mean **SELECT hive, instant, "input", "output", timeout FROM dt_inout_summary x WHERE x.hive=hive AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT hive, instant, "input", "output", timeout FROM dt_inout_summary x1 WHERE x.instant<x1.instant AND  x1.hive = x.hive)) b ON (id = b.hive)** ? seems to behave worser. Analyze added

Comment: Yes. (but you appear to have the `<` the wrong way) Plus: you need the (composite) index) Also: in the graphc plan, the main hives table is sorted twice and self-joined. Does not fit with your query.PLUS `explain ANALYZE;`, please.

Comment: Right, the image was wrong, the output of **explain analyze select * from dt_last;** is just below the image

Comment: The differences between expected and observed number of rows are too large at som places. First perform `VACUUM ANALYZE` ON all tables and see if you get a fittng plan. ALSO: I cannot explain the `((hive = x.hive) AND (instant IS NOT NULL))` condition from the `NOT EXISTS(...)` - construct. Must be a different query, IMHO.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this NOT EXISTS construct, I just thought that "last" could be translated in "!exist a record older" and not really sure about the resulting SQL. You are welcome with any other proposal

Answer (score 1):

This is the `NOT EXISTS(...)` construct, which avoids the `max()` aggregate in the subquery. It will benefit from the presense of a composite index `ON dt_inout_summary( hive, instant DESC)`

```
...
FROM hives h
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT hive, instant, "input", "output", timeout FROM dt_inout_summary x
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT 1
            FROM dt_inout_summary nx 
            WHERE nx.hive = x.hive
            AND nx.instant > x.instant
        ) 
    ) b ON (h.id = x.hive) 
 ...
```

BTW: you don't need the subquery, just a plain left join will do the same:

```
 ...
FROM hives h
LEFT JOIN dt_inout_summary x ON x.hive = h.id
     AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM dt_inout_summary nx 
        WHERE nx.hive = x.hive
        AND nx.instant > x.instant
        )  
 ...
```

, but you'll then have to reference the x.yyyyy fields in the main query ( `... x.hive, x.instant, x."input", x."output", x.timeout` )

UPDATE: The query requires 13 (1+2*6) entries Range Table Entries. This might cause the optimizer to back off.
You *could* try to add

```
SET join_collapse_limit = 16;
```

before you query. Another way would be to split off the subqueries into CTEs (CTEs are *not* broken up by the optimizer), but CTEs can be a bit slower than the corresponding subqueries:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dt_last4cte AS
WITH cte_b AS (
    SELECT *
     FROM dt_inout_summary b WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
         FROM dt_inout_summary nx
         WHERE nx.hive = b.hive AND nx.instant > b.instant)
        )
, cte_c AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM dt_temperature c WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
        FROM dt_temperature nx
        WHERE nx.hive = c.hive AND nx.instant > c.instant)
        )
, cte_d AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM dt_weight d WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
      FROM dt_weight nx WHERE nx.hive = d.hive AND nx.instant > d.instant)
    )
, cte_e AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM dt_rain e WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
      FROM dt_rain nx WHERE nx.hive = e.hive AND nx.instant > e.instant)
    )
, cte_f AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM dt_voltage f WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
      FROM dt_voltage nx WHERE nx.hive = f.hive AND nx.instant > f.instant)
    )
, cte_g AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM dt_gps g WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
      FROM dt_gps nx WHERE nx.hive = g.hive AND nx.instant > g.instant)
    )
 SELECT h0.id AS hive,
    b.instant AS inout_instant,
    b.input,
    b.output,
    b.timeout,
    c.instant AS temperature_instant,
    c.internal,
    c.external,
    d.instant AS weight_instant,
    d.weight,
    e.instant AS rain_instant,
    e.rain,
    f.instant AS voltage_instant,
    f.operational,
    f.panel,
    f.cell,
    g.instant AS gps_instant,
    g.latitude,
    g.longitude,
    g.altitude
   FROM hives h0
     LEFT JOIN cte_b b ON b.hive = h0.id
     LEFT JOIN cte_c c ON c.hive = h0.id
     LEFT JOIN cte_d d ON d.hive = h0.id
     LEFT JOIN cte_e e ON e.hive = h0.id
     LEFT JOIN cte_f f ON f.hive = h0.id
     LEFT JOIN cte_g g ON g.hive = h0.id
   -- WHERE __aditional__conditions__
   ;
```

If the typical usage of the view adds *additional conditions* to the resulting final query, a more selective plan *may* be chosen by the optimizer.

Comment: Applied this solution and update accordingly. Very nice and clean. It is ways better now but there are some sequential scans left and a select still needs seconds to be performed.

Comment: Did you run `vacuum analyze;` on all the tables? BTW: seq scans are not always bad. Sometimes they even are the best one could wish for.

Comment: Yes I did, but remains about 3/4 seconds. doying a separate query per table and per hive is still quicker (assuming I display max 10 hives per page)